# How to seach text not translate in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, i18next

I'm added i18next React for old project. So many text not can be translate. How can I search all of them in VSCode?

Some case:

```js
<Button className="w-full" onClick={onClick}>
  Save
<Button>

<Button
  type="primary"
  onClick={onCLick}
  className="ml-2"
>
  Save
</Button>

<Button>Save</Button>

<ContentWrapper title="Connection" headerAction={<Button size="small">Add</Button>}>
  <div>{`Connection`}</div>
</ContentWrapper>

<p className="mt-2 text-center">
  Drag and drop files here or <span className="text-blue-500">{t('browse')}</span>
</p>

<div>
  {mediaRecorder?.state === 'recording' ? (
    <Button onClick={handleStop}>{t('Stop')}</Button>
  ) : (
    <Button onClick={handleStart}>Start</Button>
  )}
</div>
```

Translated:

```js
<Button>{t('Save')}</Button>

<ContentWrapper title="Connection" headerAction={<Button size="small">{t('Add')}</Button>}>
      <div>{t('Connection')}</div>
    </ContentWrapper>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:

```
(<Button[\s\S\n]*?>[\n\s]*)(\w+)([\n\s]*</Button>)
```

Replace:

```
$1{t('$2')}$3
```

Comment: I update 2 case not work. It would be great if you could help me handle both cases.